# How to make possible dynamically add 'active' class to current page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to highlight current menu by adding class active to `<li>` in wordpress.
the menus are created dynamically in wordpress, is it possible to highlight current menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress does this natively.  Assuming you're using `wp_nav_menu()` to generate the html (you shouldn't use `wp_list_pages()` for nav menus though a similar answer exists if you are), it will add `class="current-menu-item"` to the current menu item.  It actually adds a whole bunch of useful classes to the menu html outlined [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/).

Is there a reason that the css class has to be `.active`?  If so, you could consider a jquery method to add the active class based on the native class.